# react native Android Cannot access realm that has been closed

Tags: react-native, realm

im using Realm inside my React native app, in IOS everything work fine, but with Android I always got this error: ***Cannot access realm that has been closed***

here is my Realm:
**RealmContext.js**

```
import { ContactInfo, Room, RoomBackground, RoomDetail, RoomMessage, Summary } from "../database/RealmSchemas"
import { Realm, createRealmContext } from '@realm/react'

const config = {
    schema: [Room.schema, 
        ContactInfo.schema, 
        RoomDetail.schema, 
        RoomBackground.schema, 
        Summary.schema, 
        RoomMessage.schema],
}

export default createRealmContext(config)
```

**Other class**

```
import RealmContext from '../../context/RealmContext'
const { useRealm, useQuery } = RealmContext
export class....{
    const realm = useRealm()
    


const getRoomDetailFromDb = () => {
        try {
            const roomDetailDb = realm.objectForPrimaryKey('RoomDetail', room.RoomId)
            if (roomDetailDb != null) {
                roomDetail = JSON.parse(roomDetailDb.value)
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
```

here is my version of realm:
"realm": "^10.18.0",
"@realm/react": "^0.3.0",

i did following the site: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/react-native/use-realm-react/

Comment: I am not sure the question is very clear. I would say you're trying to access Realm after it's gone out of scope - perhaps a var that is not being used and deallocated. Did you do some basic troubleshooting by adding a breakpoint and stepping through the code line by line, inspecting the vars and code execution until you spot something unexpected?

Comment: As asked previously; did you do some basic troubleshooting by adding a breakpoint and stepping through the code line by line? That would identify the section of code that's not working and specifically what line is crashing. If you don't want to do that you can add some console.log statements to narrow down where the code is crashing

Answer (score 0):

Seems like react-native-reanimated lib is not compatible with Realm v10 on Android.
In case you use that please try realm@11.0.0-rc.0. It works fine after I upgrade realm version to v11. Even though it's not a stable version.